# Two tables 1 variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables - each with an identical field - which we will call id. I need to pull all data from table 1 and table 2 where id = a variable such as $variable.  I have seen answers in which I can pull in data from the two tables where the id field is the same in both tables, but that's not what i am looking for. This is my current code:

```
SELECT
  topic_title,
  topic_uri
FROM bx_groups_forum_topic
  RIGHT JOIN bx_groups_forum_post
    ON (bx_groups_forum_topic.topic_id = bx_groups_forum_post.topic_id)
WHERE bx_groups_forum_topic.forum_id = '$variable'
```

Any assistance on how to properly code this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the relation between these two tables?

Comment: And what problems are your facing with this query? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

To get only data from the tables where that id `topic_id` is the same in both, try to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  t.topic_title, 
  t.topic_uri 
FROM bx_groups_forum_topic      AS t
INNER JOIN bx_groups_forum_post AS p ON t.topic_id = p.topic_id 
WHERE t.forum_id = '$variable'
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response - my only problem now is that i get no results displayed:     $groupid = '2';
 
$clients = mysql_query("SELECT t.topic_title, t.topic_uri FROM bx_groups_forum_topic AS t INNER JOIN bx_groups_forum_post AS p ON t.topic_id = p.topic_id WHERE t.forum_id = '$groupuri'") or die (mysql_error()); 
// We are going to use the "$row" method for this query. This is just my preference.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($clients)) { 
$topic_uri = $row["topic_uri"];
  
echo $topic_uri;
 
    $row_count++; 
 
}

Comment: nevermind - i am retarded. I mistyped my variable in the sql script. Thanks so much for your help